# How to delete a Google Cloud Messaging device group?

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

How do I delete a GCM device group?

Is there a REST endpoint for this?

I have looked [here](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications) but there doesn't seem to be a way to get rid of the complete device group.

I don't have the `notification_key` for the device group, only the `notification_key_name`.

Answer (score 0):

I have checked the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client-device-group) and there is no explanation yet on how to delete the entire device group. The best way you can do for now is to just [remove](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/notifications) the devices to an existing group. I found this solution that doesn't require `notification_key`. It requires keys like: `operation` set to `remove`, `id_token` set to the `idToken`, `notification_key_name` and `registration_ids`.

See the sample code below:

```
//HTTP request
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
data.put("operation", "remove");
data.put("notification_key_name", userEmail);
data.put("registration_ids", new JSONArray(Arrays.asList(registrationId)));
data.put("id_token", idToken);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, your reply refers to client managed device groups, which uses a different REST endpoint. Haven't tested whether it actually accesses the same device groups, so a device can be removed without having the `notification_key`.

Comment: But removing all registration ids in a device group doesnt remove the device group... i have tried to create a devicegroup with the samename after removing all of the registrationids still i cant create it

Answer (score 0):

```
fetch("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/notification?notification_key_name=name_of_key",                               
 {headers: {
  Authorization: "key=your_key",
  project_id:"234234...",
  "Content-Type": "application/json"                                             
 },                                                              
 method: "GET"})                                              
.then(res =>res.json())                                    
.then(json => console.log(json))
```

retrive your notification key from this code then remove individual request_token.